# Stochastic OR-function

Tags: probability, terminology, order-statistics

I need a function where the input is a list of probability values from 0 to 1, and the output is the chance that one of these probabilities comes out true.

eg.

0.5 + 0.5 = 0.75

0.9 + 0.9 + 0.9 = 0.999

Is there a standard name for this function/method/operation?

Comment: I think part of the confusion is that you're using the symbol "$+$", which means something else. A better way would be to use a new symbol, such as "$\circ$". So your examples would then be $0.5\circ0.5=0.75$ and $0.9\circ0.9\circ0.9=0.999$.

Comment: I think you should also mention that your inputs are probability values for *independent* events, and the output is the probability that at least one of the independent events occur.

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are the probabilities of two independent events, and we define $p\circ q$ to be the probability that at least one of them happens, then $p\circ q=1-(1-p)(1-q)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the complementary [cumulative distribution function of the maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Cumulative_distribution_function_of_order_statistics) of independent (but not necessarily identical) Bernoulli random variables:
$$1-\prod_i (1-p_i)$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $A,B$ are independent events, you can compute the calculation as $$\operatorname{P}(A\text{ or }B)=\operatorname{P}(A)+\operatorname{P}(B)-\operatorname{P}(A)\cdot \operatorname{P}(B)$$You should be able to see how this works by considering how "or" and "and" are represented on a logical Venn diagram and that $\operatorname{P}(A\text{ and }B)=\operatorname{P}(A)\cdot \operatorname{P}(B)$, for independent events.

Denoting the operator by the symbol $\vee$, this coincides with your examples, $0.5\vee0.5=0.5+0.5-0.5^2=0.75$ and $(0.9\vee0.9)\vee 0.9=0.999$. This last example shows how you can use multiple arguments by iteratively using the aforementioned relation. It doesn't matter which order you perform each $\vee$ in since it is associative.

The standard name is "or" or "disjunction" but I'm confused by why you're asking that since you put it in your question's title.

In general, the operator applied to all elements of a set $\{x_i\}_{1\le i\le n}$ would equal $$x_{1}+\left(1-x_{1}\right)x_{2}+\left(1-x_{1}\right)\left(1-x_{2}\right)x_{3}+...+\left(\left(1-x_{1}\right)\left(1-x_{2}\right)\left(1-x_{3}\right)...\right)x_{n}
\\
=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(1-x_j)$$